# Yii createCommand not not returning correct results

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to get a random ID from a table with a specific `visiblity=2` clause but I am having issues getting it to return the ID, it says `Undefined index: id`.

```
     $space = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
         ->select('id')
         ->from('space')
         ->where('id=rand() AND visibility=2')
         ->limit(1)
         ->queryAll();
         //->queryRow();
     echo $space['id'];
```

Is his not the correct way?

I figured out another solution using the already loaded info from my original version without guest check.

```
    $max = Space::model()->count();
    $randId = rand(0,$max);
    $space = Space::model()->find(array('offset'=>$randId));
    if ($space->attributes['visibility'] == 2) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND()` instead of `id = rand()`. Also you can use `->queryScalar()` to get only ID directly.

```
$space = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
     ->select('id')
     ->from('space')
     ->where('visibility = 2')
     ->order('RAND()')
     ->limit(1)
     ->queryScalar();

 echo $space;
```

Keep in mind that `RAND()` is slow solution. [Check alternatives](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/).
Also, if you get no entries from database, you have to check that case:

```
if (!empty($space)) { // id will never be 0
    // Do something with $space
} else {
    throw new CHttpException(404, 'No data found');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination. However I have a question, how can it randify the IDs but not get a result? If it gets a RAND() ID, it must be a ID? No? I also figured the `rand()` would be slow and found a better approach using my old method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the random id in where clause, therefore `$space` maybe an empty array based on condition. For example if you don't have a record with `id == 3` and random generated id is 3, then `$space` is an empty value. So `$space['id']` cause `Undefined index` error. You need to make sure the array is not empty and then echo id of array:

```
   if($space != null)
      echo $space['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

queryAll method gives you an array with database objects.
For your purpose you can use simpler and more understandable code:

```
$spaceId = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
     ->select('id')
     ->from('space')
     ->where('visibility=2')
     ->orderBy(RAND())
     ->limit(1)
     ->queryScalar();
echo $spaceId;
```